# HTML Lists aligning bullets with wrapped text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to align the bullets with the first line of the text that is getting wrapped up to the next line. However, I am unable to do so. By default, the bullet is aligning with the second line.
Any help would be appreciated.

```css
ul.listings {
    columns: 2;
    column-gap: 50px;
    line-height: 16px;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="listings">
   <li>
       <a href="#" title="IT,Software Development - DBA,Datawarehousing">IT/Software Development - DBA/Datawarehousing
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is the issue I am facing:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

May be you are using display flex in your "li tag". If using then you should remove display flex from li tag

you should try following code for your li tag and ul tag

CSS for ul Tag:

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}

li:before{
    content:"•";
    font-size:16px;
}
```

You can adjust Padding and Margin as your own.

Comment: your suggestion works however, it is not taking a bullet.

Comment: You can use Unicode (\2022) bullet in content?